# Plotting a polygon on a lattice grid using `\foreach`

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why does this code not compile?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3} \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3} {\draw[fill] ({(5/4)*\x},{(5/4)*\y}) circle (1.5pt)};

\draw (0,(5/4)*1) -- (0,(5/4)*2) -- ((5/4)*2,(5/4)*3) -- ((5/4)*3,(5/4)*0) -- ((5/4)*1,(5/4)*1) -- cycle;


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `\foreach { <drawing macro> };` which should be `\foreach { <drawing macro> ;}`, i.e. the semicolon before the brace. That said, you don't actually need the braces, as you only have one `\draw` in the loop.

And for the path drawing the line, you need of course use braces around coordinates that contain `()`, just like you did in the loop. In this case though, you don't need the parenthesis at all, as Zarko points out in his comment below. Another approach might be to define a `coordinate` at each point, and use the named coordinate instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
   \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3} 
      \draw[fill] (5/4*\x,5/4*\y) circle (1.5pt) coordinate (m-\x-\y);

% using named coordinates
\draw (m-0-1) -- (m-1-1) -- (m-3-0) -- (m-2-3) -- (m-0-2) -- cycle;

% or do the calculation again
\draw (0,5*1/4) -- (0,5*2/4) -- (5*2/4,5*3/4) -- (5*3/4,5*0/4) -- (5*1/4,5*1/4) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: or shorter: `\begin{tikzpicture}\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3} 
{
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3} 
\draw[fill] (5*\x/4,5*\y/4) circle (1.5pt);
}
\draw (0,5*1/4) -- (0,5*2/4) -- (5*2/4,5*3/4) -- (5*3/4,5*0/4) -- (5*1/4,5*1/4) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}` :-)

Comment: @Zarko Indeed, you are of course right. I mentioned that in my (updated) answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  You have been Johhny-on-the-Spot!  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  The syntax for `\foreach` is different than other commands.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Why does it not need a semicolon at the end?

Comment: @Adelyn That's how it's defined, as described in the manual chapter 83.  `\foreach \x in {1,2} {....};` will also work, but the semicolon isn't required. But the key point here was that the `\draw` inside the loop was *not* ended with a semicolon, so your loop produces `\draw ... \draw ...` etc. instead of `\draw ... ; \draw ... ;` etc.

Comment: @Adelyn Another way to look at it: `\foreach` on it's own doesn't start a new path, and it's paths that has to be ended with a semicolon. So it's not the same type of command.

Comment: @Zarko or shorter : `\tikz[scale=5/4]{\foreach\x in{0,1,2,3}\foreach\y in{0,1,2,3}\filldraw(\x,\y)circle(1.2pt);\draw(0,)--(0,2)--(2,3)--(3,0)--(,)--cycle;}` ;)

Comment: @Kpym, indeed shorter ... to my taste too short (one should be very familiar with `tikz` when using this syntax :-) )

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  What kind of command is `\foreach`?

Comment: @Adelyn One that doesn't start a `\path`. There was no deeper meaning to my statement. `\draw`, `\fill`, etc. are all versions of `\path`, and *by their definition* they *must* be ended with `;`. You can use `\foreach` to make multiple `\path`s, but `\foreach` in itself is *not* a `\path`.  `\foreach` can be used outside of `tikzpicture` as well by the way.